Is there an algorithm to turn any finite automata into a backwards deterministic one, with no $\epsilon$ transitions, and only one initial state?
An automaton is backwards deterministic if, for all states q, p, for all symbols a:
$$
(\delta(q, a) = \delta(p, a)) \implies p = q
$$
(I think the right translation is backwards deterministic, but english isn't my main language so please correct me if it's wrong)
If you reverse it, determinize it, and reverse it again, you might get $\epsilon$-transitions from the initial state (or multiple initial states), to the ones that were final in the reversed automaton, and I couldn't find a way of removing them without breaking backwards determinism
I tried other methods, like iteratively removing each "backwards determinism conflict", but they end up breaking when you get to the initial state, you eventually need $\epsilon$-transitions.
I'm not sure such an algorithm is possible

What is the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the source where you saw it?  What is the motivation?  Why is it interesting or useful to others?  We're looking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, so it might help to provide context, motivation, background, etc.

I might be missing something, but it seems to me like this can be done by simply adding superfluous states.
So if $\delta(p, a) = \delta(q, a)$ for some $a$ you add a new state $r$ and add it to $\delta(p, a)$.
You just have to be careful that these additional states don't break backwards determinism.

Assume that $A = (\Sigma, Q, q_0, \delta, F)$ is a NFA without $\varepsilon$-transitions.
Additionally assume WLOG that $\delta(q, a) \neq \emptyset$ for all $q \in Q$, $a \in \Sigma$.
Define a NFA $A' = (\Sigma, Q', q_0, \delta', F)$ such that

$Q' = Q \cup \{p_1, p_2, ..., p_n\}$ for $Q = \{q_1, q_2, ..., q_n\}$,
$p_i \notin Q$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, and
$\delta'(p_i, a) = \{p_i\}$ as well as $\delta'(q_i, a) = \delta(q_i, a) \cup \{p_i\}$ for all $a \in \Sigma$.

It can easily be seen, that none of the $p_i$ are part of an accepting computation.
So you can verify that $L(A) = L(A')$.
Notice that for $a \in \Sigma$

$|\delta'(q_i, a)| > 1 =|\delta'(p_i, a)|$ for all $i,j$,
$p_i \in \delta'(q_i, a)$ and $p_i \notin \delta'(q_j, a)$ for all $i \neq j$, and
$\delta'(p_i, a) = \{p_i\} \neq \{p_j\} = \delta'(p_j, a)$ for $i \neq j$.

Thus $A'$ is also backwards deterministic.

Two things I don't understand here: first, your definition of $\delta'$ seems to immediately entail that $A'$ is not backward deterministic, since $\delta'(p_i,a)\cap \delta'(q_i,a)\neq \emptyset$. Second, the WLOG part is not that easy if you want to maintain backwards determinism.

@Shaull Sorry, not sure I understand you point
Does backwards determinism imply that $\delta'(p_i, a), \delta(q_i, a)$ would be disjoint?
$A$ isn't meant to be backwards deterministic (though it might be), so the restrictions on $A$ don't need to maintain it.

yes, backwards determinism means that if two states $p,q$ can lead via letter $a$ to some state $r$, then $p=q$ (i.e., if you reverse the automaton, you'll get a deterministic automaton).

That's not exactly how it was defined in OPs post.
Using OPs definition, an automaton is backwards deterministic if $\delta(\circ, a)$ for any $a$ is injective/one-to-one.
In the context of NFAs this means that, if two states $p, q$ lead via $a$ to the same set of states, then $p = q$.

If you only consider DFAs this would reduce to your statement, but many languages like ${ab}$ don't have a backwards deterministic DFA.
So I don't think OP meant that.

right, the definition by the OP is incorrect in this sense. But I'm fairly sure this is the intention. The "set equivalence" is highly non standard.

Oh ok, thanks for the clarification.

Oh, I had misinterpreted the definition as it being $\delta(q, a) \cap \delta(p, a) \neq \emptyset \implies q=p$, but under the given definition, your answer seems to be correct, thank you!Just out of curiosity, under this new definition, would this be possible (for NFAs, I'm aware that not every DFA can be backwards deterministic, I think the simplest counterexample for that would be aa*)

@Dema No problem .
I'm honestly not sure, seems like a tricky problem.
If you really intended Shaull's definition, then you can correct your question using the "edit" button.
It would also be nice if you could add a reference like D.W. asked, all I could find were papers about $\omega$-automata.

There's not really a source I can give you. I came across the question studying for an exam, because the professor had asked this question last year. This was the way it was phrased, and your answer is correct so I'm marking it as accepted. I already took the exam anyways, so now I was mostly asking out of curiosity, just to know if the other interpretation was solvable, since I couldn't figure it out

@Shaull. I still don't get it. I also think and know that backwards determinism means that if two states , can lead via letter  to some state , then =. So I am not sure how this answer got accepted. Did the asker meant something else?

@BaderAbuRadi - it seems the OP is satisfied with this. I still think it's a cute problem, and it's puzzling that we don't have an immediate counterexample/proof.

I might have found a counterexample.
Wasn't sure if it's appropriate to put here since Dema already accepted an answer, so I've put it here.
